# Not able to find select element in selenium using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am not able to find select element in fire foc browser for the below HTML

I am trying xpath " .//*[@id='div_2_1_2_1_1_1_select']"
Please help

```
 <div id="div_2_1_2_1_1_1_formGroup" class="form-group">
        <label id="div_2_1_2_1_1_1_selectLabel" class="control-label"  for="div_2_1_2_1_1_1_select">Document Type</label>
<div id="div_2_1_2_1_1_1_formCol">
<select id="div_2_1_2_1_1_1_select" class="form-control">
<option value="ID Proof Document">ID Proof Document</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you send your code also?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to locate.

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='div_2_1_2_1_1_1_select']")))
```

Comment: You can use the code which i provided. Or else you have to remove the 'dot' at the beginning of the xpath like this                                                 //*[@id='div_2_1_2_1_1_1_select']

Comment: Check whether the content is inside a frame. If so you have to use driver.switchtTo().frame("argument"); method. Send me your code here

Comment: The element is not in the iframe. but dev has used dojo elements in the web page

Answer (score 0):

Try below:-

```
//select[@id='div_2_1_2_1_1_1_select' and @class='form-control']
```

Hope it will help you :)